# Increase resolution of figure for saving

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to increase the resolution of a figure when saving it using the matplotlib toolbar save button?

I tried increasing the dpi but it doesn't seem to make much of a difference when using the save button on the toolbar.

This is how I was increasing the dpi to what the user specified.

```
if self.txtDPI.toPlainText() == "":
    DPI = 120 
else: 
    DPI = int(self.txtDPI.toPlainText()) 
self.tempfig.set_dpi(DPI)
```

I have a GUI that the figure is on and underneath it is the matplotlib toolbar so they can edit the chart. I am trying to get it to save the figure with the set dpi when the user hits the "save" button on the matplotlib toolbar. I thought drawing the figure with the user input dpi would make it save the figure with that dpi but it doesn't. It also makes the chart go off the "canvas" if the user increases the dpi above 120.

EDIT: 
I got it to work by doing the following:

import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = DPI

Thank you for all your suggestions!

Comment: How did you try increasing the dpi?

Comment: I moved your comments to the main text of the question.  Generally, edits to the main body of questions are preferred to comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to set the `dpi` before generating the figure then I would suggest [setting the rcParams](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html). This can be done either in a `matplotlibrc` file, or if you just have one script that you want to increase the `dpi` then add something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 500
```

If on the other hand you want to be able to set the dpi when you save the figure, then you will need to extend the interactive matplotlib window. [Here is an example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/menu.html) of how that can be done in matplotlib alone

#### EDIT:

An easy way to add the interactivity would be to make use of the IPython interactive widgets. Here is a screenshot of how this could work:

[image]

Every time you move the slider, it calls `plot` with the updated value of `dpi`, so the figure is resaved. If the figure is particularly large and slow to generate you may want to use `interact_manual` instead. In order to do this just install the [IPython notebook](http://ipython.org/) with version greater than 3.0.

Comment: Hi, I have a GUI that the figure is on and underneath it is the matplotlib toolbar so they can edit the chart.  I am trying to get it to save the figure with the set dpi when the user hits the "save" button on the matplotlib toolbar.  I thought drawing the figure with the user input dpi would make it save the figure with that dpi but it doesn't.  It also makes the chart go off the "canvas" if the user increases the dpi above 120.  Is there a way to insert a picture?  Maybe that would help me explain it better.

Comment: Sorry I'm afraid without more detail as to how you have created the GUI I have no idea. The fact the plot disappears if DPI>120 suggests a bug somewhere, I would recommend trying to understand that and that may help. Good luck

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I think I will just try and remove the "save" button from the toolbar and make my own save button.

Comment: @Michelle this is what I've done in Pyside and it works.

Comment: @Greg your rcParams['savefig.dpi'] suggestion worked when I changed the rcParams for matplotlib.  Thank you!